# Check if active internet available or not ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Reachability but its showing device is connected through wifi or cellular data. I just want if device is connected to internet or not. I just used some code, its working fine but app is getting freez if device not connected to internet.

```
struct hostent*hostinfo;
char*hostname="google.com";
hostinfo=gethostbyname(hostname);
if (hostinfo == NULL){
NSLog(@"-> no connection!\n");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-macos)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thanks for your response, i already tried using hostname also its showing same like connected using wifi or data.

Comment: let me give you an example, i just connected using wifi but the net is not working. In that case also i am getting true.

Comment: I am getting timeout errors in that case, but i just want to put a check.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742601/how-to-check-internet-connection-on-ios-device

Comment: Could you please look into the question, actually using reachability we can get to know that how we connected.

Comment: Can you do this `if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable)`

Comment: or `Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];` see this https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: Yeah, i tried that. I just enable the hotspot in my mobile and i just switch off the mobile data. In that case also i am getting Reachable via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Only ***Swift***

You need to import `SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork` and bellow method works like charm for me

```
public class func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress        = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len    = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: I am looking in objective c

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURL for check internet connection

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/"];
if ([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the Internet");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the Internet");
}
```